# Cypress cannot request API or display content with the new auth0-spa-js package

Tags: auth0, cypress

I tried to sign in to Auth0 with the new package (https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js).

Attempt 1: I did try a best practice that uses `cy.request()` but seem like new the `auth0-spa-js` package now requires a random state string (which I don't have and it was generated from `loginWithRedirect` function) in the request URL. So I can not call sign in API of Auth0

Attempt 2: I set `"chromeWebSecurity": false`, I click sign in button -> my web is redirected to Auth0 page, the URL is load correctly but Auth0 refused to display '`auth0 url`' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

Does you guy have any solution for this situation?

Answer (score -1):

For now, this is the workaround solution of me.

1. Disable chrome security in Cypress config.
2. Login through the auth0 page (we will redirect to log-in page and log out due to the fact that I cannot generate the random state in the new auth0 package: auth0-spa-js)

Note: If you’re not custom login page in auth0, use the classic page in Universal Login. I found that the new UI of Auth0 login page has a lot of security enhance that prevents us render auth0 in an iframe. (like image below)

[Auth0 seting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiFCz.png)

Then, Go to Auth0 -> Tenant Setting -> Advanced -> Enable Clickjacking Protection to allow auth0 load in an iframe.

[Enalbe Clickjacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMjv2.png)

Ok, that all the step that I did to make it work. Hope this help you